# What is the query string of the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i load a page in the browser, the javascript code associated is loaded in this array : jquery.min.js/eval/seq/#number#. so i can't debug my js function because i have n files.
What is the role of this array ? and why i have many js files.

[image]

My button :

```
<input type="button" onclick="openFunction();" value="test" name="send"/>
```

my function openFunction() in test.js file
when i debug with firebug in the first click it stoped in my breakpoint but after every call it create a new file and i can't debug my function.

Comment: I think these may be for code that's loaded dynamically, e.g. with `$.getScript()` or when `.load()` or `.html()` sees a `<script>` tag.

Comment: They're all the same file - that's a querystring which forces a non-cached version of the file.  Are you saying that each page actually loads all those scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the version of the file so that the file wouldn't be there in the cache.

**To make you clear:** suppose you have `one.js`

```
<script src="one.js"></script>
```

second time you modify your one.js and to make sure that this wouldn't be there in cache you'd do change the version of the file by querying like this:

```
<script src="one.js?v=1"></script>
```

would take this file without clean refresh the browser takes the one.js file assuming it's a new file `one.js?v=1` but actually this is taking just `one.js`

**Conclusion:**

They're all the same file - that's a query string which forces a non-cached version of the file.

---

If you are seeing all of them while debugging then you can use last one file which is going to take action:

```
jquery.min.js?2.0.0/eval/seq/511
```